# Safari support for lookahead and behind RegExp

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have the following Regex, which is fine in Chrome FF but safari does like it. I am attempting to identify string that have a \n return without a space surrounding it.

Good: test /n message
Bad: test/nmessage

```
var regex = RegExp("\n(?! )|(?<! )\n");
```

**Can anyone transpose this to better support Safari?**

[image]

Comment: Do you want strings containing `\n` _with_ or _without_ spaces?  Can you add more sample data?

Comment: @Tim I would like to find all occurrences of a /n in a string that isn't separated by a space either side.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for below regex, here `$1` will contain the newline that is not surrounded by space on either side.

```regex
[^ ](\n)[^ ]
```

You can use this in javascript like below

```js
var case1 = "firstline\nsecond"; 
var match1=case1.match(/[^ ](\n)[^ ]/g)
if(match1==null) console.log("Has newlines surrounded with space");
else console.log("NO newlines with space");
```

Comment: How would I use this? Contains?